# How to create REST API with socialite and passport in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I want to create REST API which will use social (google) login system to authenticate the user into the system .

I am using laravel auth and socialite for social authentication 
so my route is like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:api'], function(){
  Route::get('hello','ApiTestControler@index');
});
```

And i m trying to access this with this url

http://localhost:8000/api/hello?token=16Wf313JyO66cgXk6UstxsIzrf0hlt8tsP09i04UczkWysHWoveVcHGhUPz6YTdX

I was expecting it to log me in and show the `ApiTestController index methord`

But its showing me login page.
How do i fix this issue and get user authenticate using the API token?

**UPDATE**

User migration table

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->boolean('activated')->default(false);
        $table->string('token');
        $table->ipAddress('signup_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('signup_confirmation_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('signup_sm_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('admin_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('updated_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->ipAddress('deleted_ip_address')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
```

And the auth configuration in `config\auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver'   => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
      ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Laravel does not know that this is an api call, it thinks that its a web call. So to fix this you need to add `application/json` on your headers :

```
Content-Type: application/json

Accept: application/json
```

As soon as you add `json` on your headers and make a call then laravel will know that is an api call! Therfore it will load your api controller.

Comment: That answer was very helpful. Now i an not getting any login for as expected.
But at the same time its showing me `Unauthenticated` even though i m providing correct token 

Now my url is something like this
  `http://localhost:8000/api/hello` and in the header 
`token: TOKEN HERE
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json`

Even after providing correct token value its the same `Unauthenticated`
Any suggestion??
I am adding my user migration table for better understanding

Comment: I am not using any route group its come by default with with laravel 5.5.
It add `api` prefix by default if you are making rest api
For authentication system i am using oAuth 2.0 
'https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth' this one i am using as my boiler plate for laravel project

Comment: well since u are using oauth 2.0 then that is another issue not from what u asked, hmm I see route grouping on your posted routes, so remove that and try to see if  u have access! If so then mark my answer as completed!

Comment: If i remove that `api` group it throw laravel error `"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",`
You see, laravel by default nest all the route in `api.php` with a prefix `api` so thats their default 

And the authentication that you asked its using basic auth that is generated by the command `php artisan make:auth` 
sorry for the error in earlier comment

Comment: okay that surely its an auth issue, close this thread and post a new question!